# remove field from tab seperated file using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to clean-up some tab-delineated files and thought that the `awk` below would remove field 18 `Otherinfo` from the file. I also tried `cut` and can not seem to get the desired output.  Thank you :).

**file**

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    Gene.refGene    GeneDetail.refGene  ExonicFunc.refGene  AAChange.refGene    PopFreqMax  CLINSIG CLNDBN  CLNACC  CLNDSDB CLNDSDBID   common  Otherinfo
chr1    949654  949654  A   G   exonic  ISG15   .   synonymous SNV  ISG15:NM_005101:exon2:c.294A>G:p.V98V   0.96    .   .   .   .   .   .   1   3825.28 624 chr1    949654  .   A   G   3825.28 PASS    AF=1;AO=621;DP=624;FAO=399;FDP=399;FR=.;FRO=0;FSAF=225;FSAR=174;FSRF=0;FSRR=0;FWDB=0.00425236;FXX=0.00249994;HRUN=1;LEN=1;MLLD=97.922;OALT=G;OID=.;OMAPALT=G;OPOS=949654;OREF=A;PB=0.5;PBP=1;QD=38.3487;RBI=0.0367904;REFB=0.0353003;REVB=-0.0365438;RO=2;SAF=335;SAR=286;SRF=0;SRR=2;SSEN=0;SSEP=0;SSSB=0.00332809;STB=0.5;STBP=1;TYPE=snp;VARB=-3.42335e-05;ANN=ISG15 GT:GQ:DP:FDP:RO:FRO:AO:FAO:AF:SAR:SAF:SRF:SRR:FSAR:FSAF:FSRF:FSRR   1/1:171:624:399:2:0:621:399:1:286:335:0:2:174:225:0:0 GOOD 399 reads
```

**desired output**

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    Gene.refGene    GeneDetail.refGene  ExonicFunc.refGene  AAChange.refGene    PopFreqMax  CLINSIG CLNDBN  CLNACC  CLNDSDB CLNDSDBID   common
chr1    949654  949654  A   G   exonic  ISG15   0   synonymous SNV  ISG15:NM_005101:exon2:c.294A>G:p.V98V   0.96    .   .   .   .   .   .
```

**awk** (runs but doesn't remove field 18)

```
awk '{ $18=""; print }' file1
```

**cut** (removes all field except 18)

```
cut -f18 file1
```

Comment: `cut -f1-17 file1` should do the trick.

Comment: in the future, realize that data that is wider than the display page is hard to manage and that you can post a problem just as easily for field 8, as field 18. Or even field 5. Good luck.

Comment: can `cut` rename the removed field  header to "Comments"? So the `18th` field header was "Otherinfo" after it is removed it is "Comments".  Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, awk uses blanks as delimiters. Therefore, you have to specify to use tabs as delimiters in your output (`OFS`):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{$18=""; gsub(/\t\t/,"\t")}1' file1
```

Comment: Can the removed field be re-named to "Comments"  after it is deleted? Maybe `($18=""; "Comments"....`. Thank you :).

Comment: Sorry, it is still not entirely clear to me what you want: How can one "rename" an already deleted field?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :).